# Javalin tutorial yielding "Unresolved reference: AtomicInteger"

Tags: maven, kotlin, javalin

Title says it. Following the [Javalin tutorial](https://javalin.io/tutorials/simple-kotlin-example) as part of learning kotlin and getting the Unresolved Reference on `mvn package`.  I imagine I need to pull in a dependency, but the example doesn't show it and Google is failing me.  My pom.xml is large-ish, but my version info is as follows:

```
<properties>
    <kotlin.version>1.1.3-2</kotlin.version>
</properties>
```

and my current dependency list is:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jre8</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.javalin</groupId>
        <artifactId>javalin</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Not really sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the class `UserDao` you've forgotten to add the following import

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
```

All the sources for the sample are available on github (https://github.com/tipsy/javalin-kotlin-example) so you can look that up as reference.

Comment: I wouldn't say I forgot so much as it wasn't listed in the tutorial and I couldn't find the docs that told me what namespace the AtomicInteger class was in. :). But thanks, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Paul if this has solved you problem, please mark the question as solved. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I hit it on my mobile but I guess it didn't sync.